# Multiple CVs on Jobs/Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Is it possible to create multiple CVs on Careers? In order to better fit employers' expectations it is often sensible to emphasise different things in your CV.

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of a cover letter?

Comment: No, CVs should absolutely be tailored to each employer just as much as the cover letter. It doesn't take long to have too much stuff to talk about and want to cherrypick by target.

Comment: No, cover letter has a slightly different aim. CV needs adjustment too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't have a way to version CVs right now and this isn't slated for upcoming development. However this is a valid use case and it is something we want to consider. I'm setting this to deferred as we'll be thinking about this in the future.

Answer (score -2):

The export to PDF feature allows you to select which sections to show, and which ones to hide, on the PDF version of your CV. Perhaps you could create a complete CV, and generate different versions by hiding the things you don't want to emphasise on for a particular potential employer?

Comment: However we cannot add 2 sections of the same type to CV, for example 2 sections "Summary" or "Education". So it's not the point. I have several degrees which are not all relevant for the same position. In one case I want to highlight one and in other case I want to emphasize another.

Comment: It wouldn't fit all use cases, I agree. But in *some* cases it may be sufficient.